# Read/write to database from quartz jobs - transactions not working

Tags: java, spring, oracle, transactions, quartz-scheduler

I have two Quartz (1.8.3) jobs, configured via Spring (2.5.6), one of them writes (send) to database, and one reads from it (check).

```
<bean id="scheduleFactory"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="Check"/>
            <ref bean="Send"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="Send" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="StatusMonitor" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="sendMessage" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="Check" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="StatusMonitor" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="checkAndUpdateStatus" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="30 0/1 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Transaction manager is set up:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="TransactionManager"/>
```

In both jobs I explicitly run read/write operations in transactions like this:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void sendMessage() {
        try {
            TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(ptm);
            tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                @Override
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                    ...
                    statusDAO.update(status);
                    ...
                }
            });
            log.info("Status was updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

where ptm is a TransactionManager bean, injected via Spring.
I see "Status was updated" record in logs, but when I read this record from transactional read method it is outdated sometimes. Moreover, when I use an SQL editor to read this record it is outdated too.
I don't understand, why transactions dont work in this case, do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `statusDAO` transactionnal (ie with the @Transactionnal annotation for example) ?

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: If problem happens "sometimes" (but log message printed each time), most likely it means that your persistence logic have flaw (JDBC or Hibernate?). Check content of "doInTransactionWithoutResult" function with all nested calls. I need more code to be more precise. If you could create minimal test isolating problem, it will help.

Comment: nico_ekito, statusDAO is not transactional, transactions are at upper level.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might be interested. This worked for me

```
<bean name="applicationDataCollectorControllerJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.mypckage.controller.jobs.ApplicationDataCollectorController" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <!--<entry key="timeout" value="1" />-->
            <entry key="genericService" value-ref="genericService" />


            <entry key="applicationDataCollectorService" value-ref="applicationDataCollectorService" />

            <entry key="transactionManager" value-ref="transactionManager" />

        </map>
    </property>



</bean>
```

--- in the scheduler bean---

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {

getApplicationDataCollectorService().collectData(transactionManager);


}
```

----In the applicationDataCollectorService bean-----

```
public void collectData( org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager transactionManager) {



        try {
            this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
            testTransactionalSave();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            BUSY = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

private void testTransactionalSave() throws Exception {

    TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus ts) {
            try {
                ApplicationParameter appPara = null;
                List<ApplicationParameter> appParaList = genericService.getListFromHQL("select o from ApplicationParameter as o order by o.id desc", false);
                if (appParaList != null) {
                    if (appParaList.size() > 0) {
                        appPara = (ApplicationParameter) appParaList.get(0);
                        appPara.setLastBankStatementMailNum(appPara.getLastBankStatementMailNum() + 10);

                        appPara = (ApplicationParameter) genericService.mergeObject(appPara);

                        System.out.println(" num is now = " + appPara.getLastBankStatementMailNum());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Note: dont forget to declare transactionManager as private properties in both beans with public setter and getter for spring to wire it up. Any Questions? yemiosigbesan@gmail.com